# Best place to stash a file so that BOTH USER AND SUDO can read/write to it

Tags: permissions, python, sudo, home-directory

I'm building a large, complex program, mostly in Python, which requires **a file to hold the configurations** for a particular installation.

To access said configurations, Python needs to know where to find the file. This is where the trouble starts:

1. At the moment, I install the configurations file to **~/configs.db**.
2. Python finds the file by looking for the **home directory** and then looking in that folder for a file called configs.db.
3. When Python is run normally, it gives the home directory as **/home/USERNAME/** and all is well.
4. But when Python is run as sudo - unavoidable for some scripts - it gives the home directory as **/root/** and then raises an exception, because it can't find a file called configs.db in there.

Where can I put a file so that **both a normal user and sudo** can read and write to it? Or is there a better way of achieving what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Would `sudo -E` suffice?

Comment: One method is to use two scripts: One runs as root and does root stuff only, it's not user-facing. The other runs as the user and does everything else. The two applications communicate using dbus.

Comment: You are correct. However, when it comes to the `configs.db` file you've referenced, even a root user won't change ownership of a file just because he/she edits it. Maybe you could use ACLs instead of regular permissions.

Comment: `sudo` is a command, not a user. When you use `sudo` (SUperuser DO), you run the command/script *as root*.

Comment: why does Python look in the home directory? It seems that the easiest way would be to, like, give the full path (instead of `~` or `$HOME`) or something. It might help to show the part of your code that is looking for the file.

Comment: @ajgringo619 That is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Please either make your comment into a full answer, or permit me to do that for you.

Comment: Go ahead, @TomHosker; glad it's going to work for you.